# Webpack 2+, how to shim Cordova

Tags: angular, cordova, webpack, shim

#### Problem

So I'm building an Angular project in Cordova, and I'm wondering if anyone know how to shim Cordova in webpack.

Normally, you reference `cordova.js` directly in your index.html, but I'm opting to avoid that, and have it included in the bundle, for tree shaking and all that. Not sure its even plausible, but I thought I'd ask since Google fu has failed me.

#### Code

I'm referencing a cordova plugin called splashscreen like so:

```
import * as splashscreen from 'cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen';
```

However this plugin has a require for cordova/exec:

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');
```

This is where webpack fails:

```
ERROR in ./~/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova/exec' in './node_modules/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www'
```

So I've tried tweaking `webpack.config.js` to get webpack to understand where cordova is located:

```
let cordova;
let cordovaExec;

if (context.opts.platforms[0] === 'ios') {
    cordova = './platforms/ios/platform_www/cordova';
    cordovaExec = 'cordova-ios/cordova-js-src/exec';
}
else {
    cordova = './platforms/android/platform_www/cordova';
    cordovaExec = 'cordova-android/cordova-js-src/exec';
}
```

And then Webpack's `ProvidePlugin`:

```
new ProvidePlugin({
            'cordova': cordova,
            'cordova/exec': cordovaExec
})
```

But the error remains...

I'm no expert when it comes to Webpack, so does anyone know the solution, if there is any?